# Python - ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Tags: python, keras, forecasting, embedding, kaggle

I'm trying to use Entity Encoding with Keras. These are my categorical and numeric features. Dataset is from the Rossmann Store Sales competition on Kaggle.

```
cat_cols = ['Store',    'DayOfWeek',    'StateHoliday', 'StoreType',    'Assortment',   'Day',  'Month',    'Year', 'Week', 'Quarter',  'DayMonth', 'MonthYear',    'Season', 'Promo',  'SchoolHoliday',
                'Promo2', 'Competitors']
cont_cols = ['hits', 'nearby_new_year', 'nearby_easter',    'nearby_christmas', 'is_Anomaly', 'CompetitionDistance']
y_train = train['logSales']

X_train = []
X_test = []
X_train.append(train[cont_cols].values)
X_test.append(test[cont_cols].values)
for cat in cat_cols:
    X_train.append(train[cat].apply(str).values)
    X_test.append(test[cat].apply(str).values)

cat_sizes = {}
cat_embsizes = {}
for cat in cat_cols:
    cat_sizes[cat] = train[cat].nunique()
    cat_embsizes[cat] = min(50, cat_sizes[cat]//2+1)

import keras.backend as K
def custom_rmspe(y_pred, y_true ):
    return K.sqrt(K.mean((y_true - y_pred)/y_true))

ins = []
concat = []
for cat in cat_cols:
    x = Input((1,), name = cat)
    ins.append(x)
    x = Embedding(cat_sizes[cat]+1, cat_embsizes[cat])(x)
    x = Reshape((cat_embsizes[cat],))(x)
   
    concat.append(x)

y = Input((len(cont_cols),), name='cont_cols')
ins.append(y)
concat.append(y)

y = Concatenate()(concat)
y = Dense(100, activation= 'relu')(y)
y = Dense(1)(y)
model = Model(ins, y)
model.compile('adam', custom_rmspe)

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 512, 3)
```

I have a problem when I'm trying to fit the model. Here is the error that pops up when I run the last cell of the code

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged, input_shape = [6, 50], output_shape = [50]
```

Please help me. Thank you in advice.